# Firefox's slow starting

Tags: 11.10, firefox

What happened with Mozilla Firefox? After updating my Ubuntu 11.10, Firefox its starting very slow. The last update was Thunderbird, Chromium and Flash player, Nothing about Firefox.

Do you experience the same issue? How can it be corrected?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try starting Firefox from the command line to see info on what's going on during startup.  In particular, you might want to use `firefox -safe-mode` to see if you get a fast startup that way.  If so, then it's probably an add-on causing the delay.

Incidentally, since someone else has suggested that a slow startup is somehow normal for Firefox, let me point out that Firefox is known to have a fast startup on 11.10.  At least, according to [this Tom's Hardware testing](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/chrome-17-firefox-10-ubuntu,3129-5.html), it beat Chrome and Opera when loading one tab.  Personally, I find the startup very swift on Precise beta2.

Comment: You right, if i disable all addons firefox comes again like normal. Will investigate the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experiencing the same issue, but one thing you could try erasing your profile or try using a different one for awhile to see if it speeds things up.

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Profiles should be able to help you with Firefox profiles.

Answer (score 0):

I saw some problems (not error, but notice or warning) about Firefox's theme engine when start on 11.10 .

But I don't think that this makes it slow down too much.

Chromium is faster than Firefox (I am a fun of Firefox by the way). If you are talking about this, it seems to be normal. Try to remove unused add-ons, that may help you make it a little faster (depending to the number of add-ons)

And just my opinion; may gnome theme for ff can cause it too.

---

Have you seen [Firefox Slow Performance](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2073/firefox-slow-performance) ? There is an answered question with a similar question???

Answer (score 0):

the default Firefox on ubuantu is from snap package
The thing about snap is it takes time to load all of its files before any app starts u can install native Firefox with
`sudo apt install firefox`
this will install native firefox which is fast on start
to remove slow snap firefox use `snap remove firefox` 
snap keeps snapshot for all snap packages u can remove that also by `snap forget 1` 1 being the first snap aplication you have removed from snap